# Calendar access from apps: only some calendars are displayed

Tags: applications, 2.1-eclair, calendar

I've Sony Ericsson X10 mini pro with Android 2.1 and root. I want to have a separate timetable calendat that will not be visible in some places (calendar app). I think I've some good reasons for creating a seperate calendar.

I sync calendars in my phone with my Google account. I've enabled auto-sync, but I've tried to force sync manually.

However, although the Sony Ericsson calendar app* can see all the calendars, other apps (e.g. Jorte, Business Calendar Beta, Profile timer and Android Agenda Widget) can't. They can see only some older calendars. Deleting visible calendars didn't solve this problem: the deleted calendars had disappeared, but the new calendars haven't been shown.

I've also tried to delete my account and resync, but it says "This account is required by some applications. You can only remove it by resetting the phone to factory defaults (which deletes all your data)...".

I've also tried to find something interresting in ddms. Error like this is displayed regurarly once a minute (almost exactly, see http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/8eey69l4/plochu1_086.png ):
`ERROR/ActivityThread(2823): Failed to find provider info for calendarEx`

*) Sony Ericsson has replaced the default calendar app by their one.

Comment: Can you see the new calendar on the Google Calendar web page using a laptop or desktop (i.e. not your phone)?

Comment: Yes, I can. The new calendars are also created from my laptop. BTW: I've found these calendars in database and they are neither shown nor synced, see http://pastebin.com/Pk6ZWn6J . I've also read that it is possible to enable them in the default Android calendar app, but, unfortunately, the Sony Ericsson's replacement is poor. :-( I've tried to extract calendar app from Android emulator, but there is no such app :-( But I've extracted the sqlite3 binary and analyzed it as mentioned above. I'm not sure if I should try update command. (I don't want to break anything.)

Comment: I just re-read the question and I'm suddenly not sure what it is you're looking for.  Is the problem that you've created a new calendar and can't see it in non-default calendar apps?  Or can none of the calendar apps see it?

Comment: The Sony Ericsson calendar app (which is poor) seems to be the only app that can see it. However, it behaves strangely: I add a new event and it is not displayed. I don't have checked whether these calendars are kept synced, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally solved it using the update command (disable sync; restart; update; restart; enable sync) and ot seems to work well. The update command was like:

```
UPDATE Calendars SET sync_events=1, selected=1 WHERE _id > 3
```

I had tried compiling the Android Calendar from source, but I was getting sone errors about invalid NDK or SDK version.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Don't forget to "accept" this answer so future readers with the same problem will know it's been solved.